# Upsert issue when using mgo

Tags: mongodb, go

Please tell me who came across this when working with Mongo through mgo. I need to update the document, if there is no document, insert a new one, I use Upsert():

```
entry := models.Example{
    ID:           bson.NewObjectId(),
    UserID:       userID,
    SessionID:    sessionID,
    Created:      created,
  }

query := bson.M{
  "$set": entry,
}

_, err = mongo.C(mongodb.ExampleCollection).Upsert(bson.M{
  "user_id":      userID,
  "session_id":   sessionID,
}, query)
```

So it inserts the document, and when updated it breaks (& mgo.LastError {Err: "Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'", ...}), if you remove the previously generated ID, then it cannot insert it without ID.

I also read about $setOnInsert, but apparently it doesn't work like this on ID:

```
query := bson.M{
  "$setOnInsert": bson.M{
    "_id": bson.NewObjectId(),
  },
  "$set": entry,
}
```

Comment: The error message seems fairly clear. You can't update an object id. Just don't set it at all, and mongodb will generate one for you when a new document is inserted.

Comment: no mongo does not set it automatically, if there is no ID in the structure, an error occurs:

&errors.errorString{s:"ObjectIDs must be exactly 12 bytes long (got 0)"}

Comment: No, if the id is present it has to be valid. If you don't set one at all it will work.

Comment: no, if I leave it blank then the specified error occurs. for example, if the record is like this, but the model has an ID, then an error will be returned:

entry := models.Example{
    UserID:       userID,
    SessionID:    sessionID,
    Created:      created,
  }

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot to add "omitempty" tag, then ID is generated, problem was that

Comment: @JohnRoget if you found the solution please add it as an answer to your question for the next one with the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my specific case, adding "omitempty" to the bson tag helped me. Without it, I could not write in one of the cases without ID, it was not generated automatically.

```golang
models.Example{
    ID    bson.ObjectId    `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    ...
}
```